# Why can't curl trust DDEV projects/domains on macOS?

Tags: macos, curl, macos-monterey, ddev

When setting up a TYPO3 project with ddev on macos 12.6.2, the `curl` command cannot access the DDEV project but doesn't trust the certificate:

```
> curl -X OPTIONS 'https://typo3.ddev.site/jsonapi'

curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.`
```

However, using the same command with `ddev exec curl https://typo3.ddev.site/jsonapi` returns a proper result:

```
> ddev ssh
[user]@typo3-web:/var/www/html$ curl -X OPTIONS 'https://typo3.ddev.site/jsonapi' 

{
"meta": {
"prefix": "ai",
"content-baseurl": "/uploads/tx_aimeos"
, "locale": {[...]}
, "resources": {[...]}
}
}
[user]@typo3-web:/var/www/html$
```

PS: My setup uses a TYPO3 extension called `Aimeos`, which offers a jsonapi. With Aimeos, it is required to initially get all the resources via the `OPTIONS` method, which returns a json.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**

In my case the solution was:

```
# Make sure to use brew's curl:
> brew install curl
> echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/libressl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc 

# Restart terminal.

> brew install ca-certificates
# or, if already installed:
> brew reinstall ca-certificates

> mkcert -uninstall
> mkcert -install
> ddev poweroff

# Remove the `mkert_caroot` from `~/.ddev/global_config.yaml`

> mkcert -uninstall && sudo chmod -R ugo+w "$(mkcert -CAROOT)" && rm -rf "$(mkcert -CAROOT)" && mkcert -install

# Reboot the computer.

> ddev start
```

**Explanation:**

Upon comparing the outputs of

```
> ddev exec curl -v 'https://api.typo3.ddev.site'
```

(which is pure Linux) and macos's

```
> curl -v 'https://api.typo3.ddev.site'
```

(which has to be the `homebrew` version!), it became clear that in my case `curl` could not see the `ca-certificates`:

```
# This output is shown only with the ddev curl command:

 * successfully set certificate verify locations:
 *  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
 *  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
```

Randy Fay (from ddev) recommended to take the following steps:

```
> brew install ca-certificates

# or, if already installed:
> brew reinstall ca-certificates

# These steps might not be necessary, but just to be sure:
> mkcert -uninstall
> mkcert -install
> ddev poweroff
> ddev start
```

In my case this resulted in a working homebrew `curl` that can access ddev domains. Thank you, Randy!

**Further things to consider**

For the sake of completeness I should mention that there were many other steps taken before this one. Here is a collection of what I can remember:

```
# Check if the proper homebrew architecture is installed (important in times of M1, Rosetta and Intel):
arch && ls -l $(which brew) && file $(which brew)
# On a M1 MacBook the output should contain `arm64`

# Make sure the proper homebrew versions of curl and libressl to your PATH 
# variable by adding the following line to your ~/.zshrc file:
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/libressl/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/curl/bin:$PATH"

# List cached/unreadable certificates:
ddev exec ls -l /mnt/ddev-global-cache/mkcert
# ...and remove them:
ddev exec sudo rm -r /mnt/ddev-global-cache/mkcert/*
```

Randy Fay from ddev recommended these steps:

1. `ddev poweroff`
2. remove the `mkcert_caroot` from `~/.ddev/global_config.yaml`
3. `mkcert -uninstall && sudo chmod -R ugo+w "$(mkcert -CAROOT)" && rm -rf "$(mkcert -CAROOT)" && mkcert -install`
4. Reboot
5. `ddev start`

He also recommended to read up on these articles:

- https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert/issues/199
- https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert/issues/431
- https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert/issues?q=is%3Aissue+in%3Atitle+curl+

It might be necessary to adapt some of the paths mentioned in those articles, e.g. the path to homebrew's ssl, which is nowadays probably  `/opt/homebrew/etc`. You can find out more by using this command:

```
> brew info openssl
```

**Further commands that might be helpful:**

```
> which mkcert
> mkcert --version
> grep mkcert_caroot ~/.ddev/global_config.yaml
```

It is possible to start a debug environment in ddev:

```
> ddev debug test

# Change "9871" in the folloing URL to whatever you get in your terminal:
> curl -I https://tryddevproject-9871.ddev.site
```